# writing fractions inside a matrix

Tags: math-mode

[image]

How to write a matrix which is showed above in latex ?
Please help me with this matrix.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you showed what you have tried so far so that we could address the specific issue you are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 6):

For the matrix, I suggest you load the `amsmath` package to gain access to the `bmatrix` ("matrix with square brackets") environment. To typeset the fractional terms, you may want to use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`. (`\dfrac` is also provided by the `amsmath` package.) Finally, I suggest you create a macro to encode the string "le". In the code below, I define `\ul` ("upper limit") to typeset the string in `\mathrm` mode, since the macro name `\le` is already taken.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for bmatrix environment and \dfrac macro
\newcommand\ul{\textrm{le}}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_0^\ul x*{\Phi_c}''\cdot {\Phi_c^T}'' \,dx =
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{6}{\ul^2} & \dfrac{2}{\ul} & -\dfrac{6}{\ul^2} & \dfrac{4}{\ul}\\[2ex]
\dfrac{2}{\ul} & 1 & -\dfrac{2}{\ul} & 1 \\[2ex]
-\dfrac{6}{\ul^2} & -\dfrac{2}{\ul} & \dfrac{6}{\ul^2} & -\dfrac{4}{\ul}\\[2ex]
\dfrac{4}{\ul} & 1 & -\dfrac{4}{\ul} & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```